# OnCollisionEnter2D is not working although trying many different things

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this as a function:

```
    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "ColliderLeft")
    {
        Debug.Log("Left");
        //transform.position(-9.5f, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

my collider, start and update function, still its not working.

```
    public Collider2D collider;

void Start()
{
    collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    OnCollisionEnter2D(collider);
}
```

my script error is Script error: OnCollisionEnter2D
This message parameter has to be of type: Collision2D
The message will be ignored.

Comment: my isTrigger on the Colliders is disabled as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to note here:
collider and collision are not the same things.
Collider2D represents a 2D collider that you have attached to a gameobject (for example a hitbox).

A Collision2D is an event that happens when Collider2D comes in contact with another Collider2D.

Note the difference: **Collider != Collision**

When a collision happens, Unity sends a message OnCollisionEnter2D to both gameObjects that are involved in a collision.
Do not try to call it in the Update because you don't have the collision to provide. Again, **Collision is not a Collider**

Change

```
public Collider2D collider;

void Start()
{
    collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>(); // this is ok
}

void Update()
{

}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) // changed Collider2D to Collision2D
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "ColliderLeft")
    {
        Debug.Log("Left");
        //transform.position(-9.5f, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```